# How to capture the click event on a link inside a frame using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp, hyperlink, frame

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 in a jsp page and I'm trying to capture the click event of any links in the frame.  The caveat is that the links are in a frame (not an iframe) and there are no divs.  The html struture is:

```
frameset
    frame with id and name
    frame with id and name
        html
            body
                table
                    tbody
                        tr
                          td
                            <a class='className' href="reference to another jsp to load"/>
...
```

I can get to the frame using this code as an example to remove all the links, which worked.

```
$('a',top.frames['frameName'].document).remove(); //This works!
```

However, I'm at a loss as to how to attach a click event handler to these links.  I started out with something simple like:

```
$('a').click(function(){ 
        alert("Click function found!");
    });
```

and have worked on this for quite a while with no success.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

**Final:**

The thing I was doing wrong was using document.ready() for placing my code.  When I moved it like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    //$('a',top.frames['myFrame'].document).remove();
    $('a',top.frames['myFrame'].document).bind('click', function(e){
        alert('In myFrame!');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

everything worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following works:

```
$('a',top.frames['frameName'].document).remove();
```

then so should:

```
$('a',top.frames['frameName'].contentDocument).click(function(){  .... });
```

Keep in mind that for this to work the frame must be loaded when you bind the click event.

Comment: That was the second thing I tried.  Using firebug I didn't see any errors in the console, but I never hit the breakpoint there, nor the alert.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard is the frame fully loaded and the a elements present in the dom when you bind to the click event?

Comment: just run that command in the console then click to see if something happens

Comment: @JamesDrinkard - see my updated answer, i switched it to be contentDocument.. it works for me